# cloud-init-nonet

Tags: networking, maas, cloud

I have the problem someone pointed in the forum. But I see everyone have this problem with VM machines. In my case is with bare metal:

When I start the machine I see cloud-init-nonet waiting for network.

```
--------------------------------
cloud-init-nonet[164.54]: gave up waiting for a network device.
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init' at Sat, 11 Oct 2014 22:23:38 +0000. Up 164.77     seconds.
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |  Address  |    Mask   |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
ci-info: |   lo   | True | 127.0.0.1 | 255.0.0.0 |         .         |
ci-info: |  eth1  | True |     .     |     .     | 68:XX:ca:YY:09:50 |
ci-info: |  eth0  | True |     .     |     .     | 00:XX:8c:YY:c7:00 |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
ci-info: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Route info failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
2014-10-12 00:25:44,469 - DataSourceMAAS.py[CRITICAL]: Giving up on md from ['http://172.16.0.40/MAAS/metadata//2012-03-01/meta-data/instance-id'] after 126 seconds
2014-10-12 00:25:44,469 - util.py[WARNING]: No instance datasource found! Likely bad things to come!
--------------------------------
```

Is almost the same thing as seen here:

https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/28297/cloud-init-nonet-waiting-and-fails/

I also tried to explain in this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1345433

As I told in the bug it seems to me that openvswitch is not started in order. But I don't know. Maybe it's just my network config that's relaying on openvswitch db.

My config is rather simple /etc/network/interfaces:

```
### This does nothing, but left here for future reference. It should work. It's supposed to be openvswitch support on startup
allow-ovs br-ext
iface br-ext inet manual
        ovs_type OVSBridge
        ovs_ports eth0


# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
        up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
        up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
        down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
        down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual 
        up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
        down ifconfig $IFACE down


#This also does nothing as br-int is not created when this script is executed
auto br-int
iface br-int inet dhcp
```

Any help on how to solve this? This really messes my startup so much that I'm thinking about removing MAAS and reinstall without the cloud-init stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. login with :gui by login/pass: vagrant/vagrant
2. modify the `/etc/rc.local` file 
   to include the line `sh /etc/init.d/networking restart` just before `exit 0`
3. disable :gui
4. vagrant up or vagrant reload

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/391#issuecomment-2078383